# Promise callback could not be found

Tags: node.js, blockchain

I am trying to use chainpoint. I have a few hashes and am trying to submit them to chainpoint to create a timestamp proof and then anchor them to a public blockchain.

I am using the github tutorial https://github.com/chainpoint/chainpoint-js

But I am getting an error as

> (node:8796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Argument  must be
>   a non-empty Array
>       at S (C:\Users\Unmesha Banarjee\node_modules\chainpoint-js\dist\bundle.js:1:6002)
>       at H (C:\Users\Unmesha Banarjee\node_modules\chainpoint-js\dist\bundle.js:1:6533)
>       at de (C:\Users\Unmesha Banarjee\node_modules\chainpoint-js\dist\bundle.js:1:15276)
>       at Module. (C:\Users\Unmesha Banarjee\node_modules\chainpoint-js\dist\bundle.js:1:15596)
>       at tryCatch (C:\Users\Unmesha Banarjee\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:40)
>       at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\Unmesha Banarjee\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:274:22)
>       at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\Unmesha
>   Banarjee\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:97:21)
>       at me (C:\Users\Unmesha Banarjee\node_modules\chainpoint-js\dist\bundle.js:1:15336)
>       at a (C:\Users\Unmesha Banarjee\node_modules\chainpoint-js\dist\bundle.js:1:16954)
>       at C:\Users\Unmesha Banarjee\node_modules\chainpoint-js\dist\bundle.js:1:17015 (node:8796)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 2) (node:8796) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Can anyone help me...

Comment: Can you add your code, please? Or is it the exact same as https://github.com/chainpoint/chainpoint-js#tldr ?

Comment: Its the exact same code

Comment: Now I added a try catch block as var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  throw new Error('Uh-oh!');
});

p1.catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e); // "Uh-oh!"
});

Comment: But now I get proofs for six of them(hashes) and 3 hashes do not get verified proofs, also the proofs get anchored only to chainpoint calendar and not to public blockchain